# Rosserial HelloWorld On Mac OS X vs. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, macosx, rosserial, rosserial-client, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I'm attempting to use rosserial on a DAGU T'REX Motor controller to receive statuses and send commands to it, but I wanted to become familiar with rosserial first. So, I began working through the tutorials for rosserial, initially on my Ubuntu 14.04 VM (where my installation of ROS indigo resides), specifically the Publisher tutorial for my Arduino Mega 256. Everything worked beautifully and without a hitch. I was able to see the topic and subscribe to it to receive the published "hello world!" string. But, if work through the same tutorial on the Mac side (setting up the IDE and compiling/uploading the sketch), and then connect my arduino back to my Ubuntu VM, rosserial_python will never synch up to forward the topic to the ROS system. One thing to note: to setup ros_lib for my Mac, I just copied the ros_lib folder from the libraries folder on my VM to the libraries folder on my Mac.

Would anyone have a suggestion as to my this may be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191657/rosserial-helloworld-on-mac-os-x-vs.-ubuntu-14.04/) by [Donny3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/3991/donny3000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured this out myself.  There was a configuration issue of my IDE that was causing this problem.

---

Originally posted by [Donny3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/3991/donny3000/) with karma: 55 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Harry](https://answers.ros.org/users/3616/harry/) on 2015-08-04**:
Hi

I wonder if you can share your experience with this Motor controller (DAGU T'REX) and if you had test it in ROS JADE

Thanks

**Comment by [Donny3000](https://answers.ros.org/users/3991/donny3000/) on 2015-08-07**:
Well, I was having a great experience with the controller, but I made the noob mistake of dropping a nut and washer on it while in the lab and fried the board.  But, I can't work any further on it because the board is discontinued.